# Выравнивание логотипа

Tags: html, css

Нужно выровнять логотип по центру, а не влево. Код логотипа из index.php

```
<a href="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site;?>" title="<?php echo $mosConfig_sitename; ?>"><img alt="<?php echo $mosConfig_sitename; ?>" src="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site;?>/templates/minecraft/images/logo.png" width="940" height="145" border="0" align="bottom"/></a>
```

Скрин:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="display:block; margin:0 auto;">
  <a href="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site;?>" title="<?php echo $mosConfig_sitename; ?>">
    <img alt="<?php echo $mosConfig_sitename; ?>" src="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site;?>/templates/minecraft/images/logo.png" width="940" height="145" border="0" align="bottom"/>
  </a>
</div>
```